# error[E0277]: the trait bound `Project: Serialize` is not satisfied, note: required by a bound in `near_sdk::serde_json::to_vec`

Tags: rust, serde, near

```
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug)]
pub struct Project {
    pub name: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub image: String,
    pub owner: AccountId,
    pub supporters: UnorderedMap<AccountId, Supporter>,
    pub balance: u128,
    pub goal: u128,
    pub end_time: u64,
    pub status: ProjectStatus,
    pub plan: SupporterPlans,
    pub level_amounts: LookupMap<SupporterLevel, u128>,
}

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, PanicOnDefault)]
pub struct Nearkick {
    current_id: u64,
    projects: UnorderedMap<u64, Project>,
}
```

causes `` error[E0277]: the trait bound `Project: Serialize` is not satisfied, note: required by a bound in `near_sdk::serde_json::to_vec` ``  error.

If I add Serialize and Deserialize to it like this:

```
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, PanicOnDefault)]
#[serde(crate = "near_sdk::serde")]
pub struct Nearkick {
    current_id: u64,
    projects: UnorderedMap<u64, Project>,
}
```

I get this error `` error[E0277]: the trait bound `UnorderedMap<u64, Project>: Serialize` is not satisfied, note: required by `near_sdk::serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field` ``

Cargo.toml

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
near-sdk = "4.0.0-pre.2"

[profile.release]
codegen-units = 1
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
debug = false
panic = "abort"
overflow-checks = true
```

I tried adding Serialize and Deserialize to all of my structs and enums, but I still get the error.

Comment: What's the definition of `Project`?

Answer (score 1):

You have two methods:

- First, use `HashMap` rather than `UnorderedMap`.
- Second, according to [How can I serialize a near-sdk-rs LookUpMap that uses a String as a key, or is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69096013/how-can-i-serialize-a-near-sdk-rs-lookupmap-that-uses-a-string-as-a-key-or-is-t) and https://www.near-sdk.io/contract-interface/serialization-interface#overriding-serialization-protocol-default, you add the `#[result_serializer(borsh)]` and/or the `#[serializer(borsh)]` where appropriate in the `impl` function that raises the error (check your Debugging info when compiling for which file and line it raises `trait bound not satisfied` error). **You change the function, not the struct, in this case!**